# I need to create a rest API in node that calls another API

Tags: node.js, express, axios, get, postman

I need to create a REST API in my node app, that GET data from an external API - https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?category=%7Bcategoryname%7D&apiKey=APIKEY

The condition is that this rest API should contain id of the user in DB.
Only when we trigger an API with valid userID, it should return response as the data coming from external API.
otherwise show error

Can you help me build a function that would do so?

I am using mongoDB

I am writing few snippets of code i wrote to accomplish this, but i am pretty bad at it. So any help on this will be highly appreciated:

app.js

```
router.get('/api/Users/news/:id', controller.newsget);


router.get('/api/Users/news/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;  
  
    for (let i = 0; i <User.length; i++) {
        let user = User[i]
        if (user.id === id) {
            axios
                .get('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=general&apiKey=36f3e29b704f41339af8439dc1228334')
                .then(response => {
                let userData = response.data;
                res.send(userData);})
                  
                
        }
    }
  
  });
```

controller.js

```
exports.newsget = (req, res)=>{
    if(!req.body){
        return res
            .status(400)
            .send({ message : "Data to update can not be empty"})
    }

    const id = req.params.id;
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, { useFindAndModify: false})
        .then(data => {
            if(!data){
                res.status(404).send({ message : `Cannot Update user with ${id}. Maybe user not found!`})
            }else{
                res.send(data)
            }
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            res.status(500).send({ message : "Error Update user information"})
        })
}
```

I have very little clue on the approach, but i badly need assistance. Please help

I have tried mimicking some online functions to search the user and then try to fetch data from external API if the user's ID was present in my DB. But it failed

Comment: What is your actual coding problem that you want help with?  This site works best if you show a piece of code you wrote and ask a specific question about that piece of code.  Describe the problem you ran into.  Describe what you were expecting to happen or want to happen with that code.  While you show several snippets of code, you don't seem to ask a specific question about any of them.  Saying something "failed" is not a helpful description of a problem.  If something isn't working and you want help with, then describe EXACTLY what did happen and what you were expecting to happen.

Comment: Also, why do you show two separate route handlers that both start with `router.get('/api/Users/news/:id', ...)`?  Only the first one will process the route.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are writing two GET methods for same route, from what I am being concluding that, the first route should be POST according to what I am suspecting to be your functionality is depicted as follows

```
router.post('/api/Users/news/:id', controller.newsget);


router.get('/api/Users/news/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;  
  
    for (let i = 0; i <User.length; i++) {
        let user = User[i]
        if (user.id === id) {
            axios
                .get('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=general&apiKey=36f3e29b704f41339af8439dc1228334')
                .then(response => {
                let userData = response.data;
                res.send(userData);})
                  
                
        }
    }
  
  });
```

Also if you are picking the logged in user, use `req.user.id`